# Multiple VirtualHost Configuration files in Apache2.

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, unix, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have servers with RHEL-5, Apache-2.2.22, PHP-5.3.25

I know I can configure multiple virtualhost configurations in mutliple file by including these files in httpd.conf.

Can Apache support this arrangement while any incorrect configuration in one file doesn't affect another or I can say Apache as whole.

I have LOAD BALANCE server arrangement in which I want different users to have their working shells. Now we want to give them access to modify there virtualhost configurations as they like and apply them without affecting other site.

This user based working environment is possible in IIS, do Apache also support this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Apache processes its configuration file in order. Includes are processed at the point and the order they're referenced in, effectively creating a single configuration.

To have changes there take effect apache needs to be reloaded/restarted. That can fail so is not something users should be allowed to do.

The typical way to allow user to somewhat modify/override their configuration is via .htaccess local overrides, not by allowing them to modify the actual apache configuration files.